# I have an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error that I cannot trace

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app that worked up to just recently. 
The error in the Google play store is as follows:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application org.marsfirst.mars_app: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.marsfirst.mars_app" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.marsfirst.mars_app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.marsfirst.mars_app-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4703)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.marsfirst.mars_app" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.marsfirst.mars_app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.marsfirst.mars_app-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
... 11 more
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;//this gives me a warning that states its unused but it has been used in the past
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;//this gives me a warning that states its unused but it has been used in the past

import android.app.Activity;//this gives me a warning that states its unused but it has been used in the past
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



import com.parse.ParseException;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import com.parse.LogInCallback;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String un, pw;
    public TextView username;
    public EditText pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editloginusername);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpass);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                un = username.getText().toString();
                pw = pass.getText().toString();

                ParseUser.logInInBackground(un, pw, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            new CallMainPage().execute();

                        } else {
                            // username.setText("");
                            pass.setText("");
                            makeToast("User name or password not recognized.");

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new CallSignup().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class CallSignup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public class CallMainPage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainPage.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void makeToast(String text) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

My manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app" />

    <application
        android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Signup"
            android:label="@string/signup"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPage"
            android:label="Main Page" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Webpage"
            android:label="Website"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TeamNews"
            android:label="Team News"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OprPage"
            android:label="OPR Page"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MechPage"
            android:label="Mechanical Page"
            android:parentActivityName="org.marsfirst.mars_app.MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DriveNews"
            android:label="Drive News"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainPage" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProgramingPage"
            android:label="Programming Page"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainPage" >
            <intent-filter />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainPage" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

File Explorer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS1Gw.jpg

I am unsure if it is a Code error or not, due to my research I believe it is a buildpath error however everything I have tried seems to fail please help 
I will post any Additional screen shots or code that is needed. In attempt to fix the problem one "fix" I found was to change every thing to `android:name=".DriveNews"` instead of `android:name=org.marsfirst.mars_app.DriveNews` which was what it was originally 
Thank you for any help you may be able to give.

Comment: Have you checked the libraries that you use in order and export?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am a noob in android development.

I think you would like to verify the following permission tags:

```
<permission
    android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app" />
```

The classloader is not able to find a class `org.marsfirst.mars_app`. From your code it seems like mars_app is a package. Same for `android:name` in application name.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app"
```

to

```
android:name="org.marsfirst.mars_app.YourApplicationClass"
```

where `YourApplicationClass` is the class that is extending `Application` class. If you don't have any such class just remove the `name` attribute.

According to official documentation of the [application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) tag the `name` attribute should be

`The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's components.`

`The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.`

Answer (score 0):

can show you file explore?

e.g. 
[image: it's is eclipse file explorer from web]

Comment: Do you want to use dynamic loader approach? If yes, i think problem is loaded class file you not put to you device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export and check the libraries that you use in your project.

Comment: I have done that several times and I constantly cleaned and build but it still does not work

Comment: Seems you are using support library then try making following changes.   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="7"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> in your manifest.  https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#manifest

Answer (score 0):

Do you use proguard in your application?

if yes: check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring) from developer.google site. It may help you

> The default `proguard.cfg` file tries to cover general cases, but you might encounter exceptions such as ClassNotFoundException, which happens when ProGuard strips away an entire class that your application calls.

You can fix errors when ProGuard strips away your code by adding a -keep line in the proguard.cfg file. For example:

-keep public class < MyClass >

Comment: How would I check if proguard was used. I worked with a team so I am unsure.

Comment: Open '<project_root>/project.properties' and check if 'proguard.config' property is set or not.
You would see something like this : 'proguard.config=proguard.cfg'